# How to split multiple graphql queries

Tags: javascript, graphql

Given the request with multiple queries:

```
query mainQuery(
    $paramOne: Int
    $paramTwo: Int
  ) {
    queryOne(
        paramOne: $paramOne
    ) {
      totalCount
    }
    queryTwo(
        paramOne: $paramOne
    ) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
```

split these queries into two different queries as:

```
  query mainQuery(
    $paramOne: Int
  ) {
    queryOne(
        paramOne: $paramOne
    ) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  query mainQuery(
    $paramTwo: Int
  ) {
    queryTwo(
        paramTwo: $paramTwo
    ) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
```

Is it possible? Maybe i missed some utility function

Comment: What do you mean by "utility function"? Do you expect to pass it the source string (or AST) of the query, and get back multiple strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty specific use case. The core library doesn't have any utility function like that and it's unlikely any other library would.

To write your own function, you'd call `parse` on the query string in question. You'd then grab the first definition in the document node and map it's selection set into separate documents. Something like:

```
const { parse, print } = require('graphql')
const originalDocument = parse(query)
const operationDefinition = originalDocument.definitions[0]
const selections = operationDefinition.selectionSet.selections
const splitQueries = selections.map(selection => print(
   ...originalDocument,
   definitions: [
      {
        ...operationDefinition,
        selectionSet: {
           ...operationDefinition.selectionSet,
           selections: [selection]
        }
      }
   ]
))
```

However, this will only work for very simple queries. If you have variables, you'll need to walk each resulting document and remove any unused variables. Similarly, if you use fragments, you'll need to make sure those are included in the `definitions` but only if they are actually used inside the operation.